# Camview request Focus on touch

Tags: android, android-camera

I am using this library [CamView](https://github.com/LivotovLabs/CamView)  from LivotovLabs to scan barcodes. It works as expected however it does not focus for specific phones so I want to implement a focus on touch  and my solution is as below. However its not working,the phone does not focus on the barcode.

```
    camera = (ScannerLiveView) findViewById(R.id.camview);
    camera.setFocusable(true);
    camera.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

    camera.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            camera.requestFocus();
            return true;
        }
     });

    camera.setScannerViewEventListener(new ScannerLiveView.ScannerViewEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScannerStarted(ScannerLiveView scanner) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onScannerStopped(ScannerLiveView scanner) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onScannerError(Throwable err) {
            Toast.makeText(ACME_Scanner.this, "Scanner Error: " + err.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCodeScanned(String data) {
            Toast.makeText(ACME_Scanner.this, "Barcode No: "+data, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }
    });

    findViewById(R.id.btnFlash).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            toggleFlash();
        }
    });

    findViewById(R.id.btnSkip).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    ZXDecoder decoder = new ZXDecoder();
    decoder.setScanAreaPercent(0.5);
    camera.setDecoder(decoder);
    camera.startScanner();
}

@Override
protected void onPause()
{
    camera.stopScanner();
    super.onPause();
}

public void toggleFlash()
{
    try {
        flashStatus = !flashStatus;
        camera.getCamera().getController().switchFlashlight(flashStatus);
    }
    catch (NullPointerException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```